# ConfirmDialog prevents DataTable from Pagination in Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Good afternoon,

I'm using a column in a datatable which contains an action button to delete this record . When the action button is clicked, a confirmation dialog is shown where the user either could cancel or delete the record. When the record is deleted the pagination does not work anymore. I can reproduce this behaviour with PF 4.0 and also with the actually snapshot from Google Code PF 5. Here is an very easy example to reproduce:

CategoryController.java

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CategoryController {

  private Entity category;
  private List<Entity> categories;

  public CategoryController() {
    categories = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      Entity newTest = new Entity(i);
      categories.add(newTest);
    }

  }
  public void removeCategory(){
    categories.remove(category);
  }

  public Entity getCategory() {
    return category;
  }

  public void setCategory(Entity category) {
    this.category = category;
  }


  public List<Entity> getCategories() {
    return categories;
  }

  public void setCategories(List<Entity> categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
  }
}
```

Entity.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Entity implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4544407140706106480L;
  long id;

  Entity(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (id != ((Entity)o).id) return false;

    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
  }
}
```

text.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:panel header="#{langRes['setupCategories.pageTitle']}" style="height: 540px;" id="categoryTablePanel">
                <!-- category table -->
                <p:dataTable value="#{categoryController.categories}" var="category"
                             rows="10" id="categoryTable" emptyMessage="#{langRes['setupCategories.emptyTable']}"
                             paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top">
                    <!-- category id column -->
                    <p:column headerText="#{langRes['setupCategories.idEntry']}" id="idColumn" width="90%">
                        <p:outputLabel id="categoryId" value="#{category.id}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="#{langRes['setupCategories.idEntry']}" id="editColumn" width="10%">
                        <p:commandButton value="Delete" oncomplete="PF('confirmDialog').show()">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{category}" target="#{categoryController.category}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:panel>
            <p:confirmDialog global="true" widgetVar="confirmDialog" id="confirmationDialog">
                <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"
                                 action="#{categoryController.removeCategory}"
                                 update=":setupCategoryForm:categoryTable"
                                 onclick="PF('confirmDialog').hide();"/>
                <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
            </p:confirmDialog>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: ViewScoped is using CDI annotation or JSF? @javax.faces.view or @javax.faces.bean?

Comment: CDI Bean with @javax.faces.view

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to use confirmaDialog like that because you define it as Global.

I always implements confirmation like this:

Before close form:

```
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">  
        <p:commandButton value="Si" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>  
        <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>       
    </p:confirmDialog>
```

Button inside datatable:

```
<p:commandButton id="EliminarRegistro" update=":form:mainDataTable,:form:growl" process="mainDataTable" 
                        icon="ui-icon-closethick" title="Eliminar" disabled="#{!aiCarreraBean.permisosCrud.eliminar}"
                        actionListener="#{aiCarreraBean.eliminarEvent}" 
                        onclick="selectCurrentRow_paginator(dt,#{rowIndex})" > 
                        <p:confirm header="Confirmación" message="¿Seguro desea eliminar el registro?" icon="ui-icon-alert" /> 
                    </p:commandButton>
```

Javascript Class, when table is the variable widget of the table;

```
function selectCurrentRow_paginator(table,index){

table.unselectAllRows();
table.selectRow(index-(table.paginator.cfg.page*table.paginator.cfg.rows) ,false);
//table.selectRow(index ,false);

}
```

I hope you resolve your issue. Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But how do you get the selected record?  You can't use a PropertyActionListener?

Comment: Yeah! You can use PropertyActionListener (It's best for your case I think), but this is my own implementation where i select a row when i clicked that button with a js function:

Comment: It's seems to be a problem with Primefaces 5...Datatable and CommandButton does not work together anymore.